# Can't use AWS on watchOS?

Tags: watchconnectivity, watchos-5

I need to develop an application for Watch OS, which will be download the chosen files from amazon web services. But for that I need aws sdk for watch. I haven't found any on the web. Is it possible to modify the AWS SDK for iOS so it can be used for Watch?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Applications on the Apple Watch do need the companion application on the paired iPhone in order to perform more sophisticated tasks as well as to offload communication with backends such as AWS. With this SDK you can update application context information as well as send messages back and forth and transfer larger files between the app and the watch,.

Apple provides an SDK, called WatchConnectivity, to handle communication between the two devices (see [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity)).

Comment: Any AWS SDK for watchOS?

Comment: Not directly for the Apple Watch. You might have look at https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/ for an AWS SDK for iOS. You need to implement your application logic on the iPhone, but then you need to use the WatchConnectivity SDK to connect to your watch in order to present your data or retrieve data from the watch.